# Move an element below another in DOM

Tags: jquery

Struggling to get this code to work to move the .meta div to sit below the h3 in the DOM. It works, but does it twice as there are 2 instances of this code on the page, I want it to work both times, but not display two versions of the .meta div... so both dates appear....?? What am I doing wrong ?

```js
(function($) {
  $('.home_FeedsWrapper .vc_col-sm-4 .post-header .meta').each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($('h3'));
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home_FeedsWrapper">

  <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="article-content-wrap">
      <div class="post-header">
        <span class="meta"> 23 November 2022 </span>
        <h3 class="title">This is the title here</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="article-content-wrap">
      <div class="post-header">
        <span class="meta">18 October 2022 </span>
        <h3 class="title">This is another title that sits here</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to specify which ```h3```, select it with ```$(this).next('h3')```

Comment: Many thanks! got it... that was driving me mad! I thought as I was using (this) already it would not need it.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert each date after the [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) `h3` like this :

```js
$(this).insertAfter($(this).next("h3"));
```

```js
$('.home_FeedsWrapper .vc_col-sm-4 .post-header .meta').each(function() {
  $(this).insertAfter($(this).next("h3"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home_FeedsWrapper">
  <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="article-content-wrap">
      <div class="post-header">
        <span class="meta"> 23 November 2022 </span>
        <h3 class="title">This is the title here</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="article-content-wrap">
      <div class="post-header">
        <span class="meta">18 October 2022 </span>
        <h3 class="title">This is another title that sits here</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
(function($) {
  $('.home_FeedsWrapper .vc_col-sm-4 .post-header').each(function(i, el) {
    var meta = $(".meta", el).detach();
    meta.insertAfter($("h3", el));
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home_FeedsWrapper">

  <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="article-content-wrap">
      <div class="post-header">
        <span class="meta"> 23 November 2022 </span>
        <h3 class="title">This is the title here</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="article-content-wrap">
      <div class="post-header">
        <span class="meta">18 October 2022 </span>
        <h3 class="title">This is another title that sits here</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This ensures that each header is reviewed and the elements are only moved within that header. First, we detach the Span, and then insert it after the Header3.